# trouble with custom imports Python3

Tags: python, module

I am trying to import my own files in Python3. My directory looks like this:

```
/path/folder/__init__.py
/path/folder/custom_module2.py
/path/folder/custom_module.py
/path/launcher.py
```

init:

```
import custom_module
```

custom_module:

```
import custom_module2
def custom_function:
    custom_module2.custom_function()
    print('world')
```

custom_module2:

```
def custom_function2:
    print('hello')
```

launcher:

```
import folder
custom_function()
```

it says that there is no module named custom_module

Comment: That's not how you define a function `def custom_function:`

Answer (score -1):

Actually, if you just put an empty file called `__init__.py` file, python will treat the directory as a package and you can import it with the dot notation.

```
__init__.py
custom_module2.py
custom_module.py
```

then from launcher.py

```
from folder.custom_module import custom_function
custom_function()
```

> The **init**.py files are required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages; this is done to prevent directories with a common name, such as string, from unintentionally hiding valid modules that occur later on the module search path. In the simplest case, **init**.py can just be an empty file, but it can also execute initialization code for the package or set the **all** variable, described later.

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#Packages

Comment: This means running the script `launcher.py` will only work when executing from within the same directory.  Not ideal.

Comment: Hmm, what do you exactly mean? How is your solution different in that manner?

Comment: Try your approach and see.  Unless you execute from the same directory as the script is contained in, this will also fail with an `ImportError`.

Comment: I'm launching `launcher.py` from a different directory and it looks fine, or did I get you wrong?